# How to remove default 01/01/0001 in view in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a textbox field that needs to allow the user to select the date, for some reason it is showing as:

01/01/0001,

(or even for an integer field it is showing 0).

It allows for a datepicker and that works fine, but how do I change that default value, is there way to have it blank instead?

How do I change this to remove that default?

I tried making my properties in my data model to nullable in my DbContext. This seem to work before, but am not sure if I changed something and its no longer showing as MM/dd/yyyy in the textbox.

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

public int? Year { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<input class="Date" asp-for="Date" type="date" />

<input class="Year" asp-for="Year" type="text" />
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult ShowDate(string userName = null)
{
  var model = getModel.GetViewModel(userName);
  return View(model);
}
```

I expect to have mm/dd/yyyy or something similar to display as a placeholder.

Comment: Are you passing a model when you return the view from a get request?

Comment: Please add controller logic for action returning the view.

Comment: What is your issue with `DateTime? Date` and `int? Year`, it shows correctly value `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: @KristianneNerona yeah, I passing a view model to View(), I added the controller to the question.

Comment: @TaoZhou The issue is that it is not showing correctly for me on the page, I'm not getting `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: What is the value for this `model`?

Comment: It returns a Datetime value and Int value.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
<input class="Date" asp-for="Date" type="date" value=0 />
```

And just in case it doesn't, you have to make sure in your Controller that what it's receiving from the evaluation is a valid date; or make sure that date is not before any specific date you set by default, in which case should return null or " " and that should do the trick.